# laravel ajax, How to send form having value='put' successfully?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm making function that if edit form is sent using ajax, validate and send response to view. But, page load on new URL like `localhost:8000/comment/id`. and the page shows messages that I want. How can I get that response in view not reloading?

HTML

```
<form class="modify-form" method="post" action="{{ route('comment.update', $mypage->id) }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    <p class="comment-message">{{ $mypage->message }}</p>
</form>
```

Route

```
Route::match(['put', 'patch'], 'comment/{id}', ['as'=>'comment.update', 'uses'=>'MyPageController@update']);
```

jQuery

```
var $writeForm = $('form.visitor');
$writeForm.find('.write').click(function(e){

    var url = $writeForm.attr('action');

    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: $writeForm.serialize(),
        success: function(res){
            if (res.status) {
                location.reload();
            }
        },
        error: function(res){
                $writeForm.after('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+res.responseJSON.errors+'</div>')
                //console.log(res.responseJSON.errors);
        }

    });

});
```

Controller

```
public function update($id) {

    $validator = validator::make($data = Input::all(), mypage::$edit);

    if($validator->passes()) {

        $mypage = mypage::findOrFail($id);

        $message = Request::input('message');
        $mypage->update(['message' => $message]);

        $mypage->save();

        $response = array();
        $response['status'] = true;

        return response()->json($response);

    }

    if ($validator->fails()) {

        $response = array();

        $response['status'] = false;
        $response['errors'] = $validator->errors()->all();

        return response()->json($response, 400);

    }

}
```

Comment: I would reccommend using Vue.js, I know this may not be the answer you're after but its a great suggestion since vue.js is lightweight easy to use and has great compatability with Laravel. 

It allows you to pull and post data from the back end with ease and has a lot of methods at your disposal comapred to vanilla Ajax methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Partial (small view) for the comment.

Then, when you create / update the comment, Laravel can return the view for the comment, and with JQuery append it to the HTML.

You can create the partial for the commment: (Very simple)

`<p>{{$comment}}</p>`

You can return the partial like any view:

`return view('partials.comment')->with('comment', $comment);`

Then back in JS append it like:

`$("#comments-container").append(res);`

Comment: Can I request some example please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Ajax:

```
type: $('input[name="_method"]').val(),
data: $writeForm.serialize(),
success: function(res){
    if (res.status == true) {
        // Reload the current page, without using the cache
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
},
```

> Controller:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => false,
        'errors' => $validator->errors()->all()
    ], 400);

}

if($validator->passes()) {
    $mypage = mypage::findOrFail($id);

    $message = Request::input('message');
    $mypage->update(['message' => $message]);
    $mypage->save();

    return response()->json(['status' => true], 200);
}
```

Comment: just on new url , {"status":false,"errors":["The message field is required."]} is shown

Comment: {"status":false,"errors":["The message field is required."]} is right , but I want to bring that on my page. not new page

Comment: now you need to display this message inside you view page. using jquery `each` function inside the error: function() {}` block

Comment: error: function(res){
                $writeForm.after('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+res.responseJSON.errors+'</div>')
                //console.log(res.responseJSON.errors);
        } is that wrong ?

Comment: I thought that responses are not sent back.

Comment: like so: `error: function(res){ $.each(res.errors, function(i, error) {  
                $writeForm.after('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">'+ error +'</div>');
        });  }`

Comment: same. on page url:`http://localhost:8000/comment/id` show{"status":false,"errors":["The message field is required."]}

Comment: do you want to reload your page on the response?